# Yii if elseif conditions

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to set up a popup modal for a button with 2 conditions;

Here is the condition when a user hasn't saved their request for proposal draft in which - when the button is clicked - a popup will appear:

```
<?php if($model->isDraft()): ?>
    <a class="btn btn-sd btn-sd-ghost btn-sd-ghost-black full-width" href="#confirm-popup">Add More IDE <i class="icon-arr-down"></i></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here is the code for when the request for proposal has been saved to draft and the button link which - when it is clicked - will redirect to another page:

```
<?php if($model->save()): ?> 
    <a class="btn btn-sd btn-sd-ghost btn-sd-ghost-black full-width" href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('//idea/frontend/explore') ?>">Add More IDE <i class="icon-arr-down"></i></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm not sure how to combine these two conditions into one so it won't show two buttons.

Comment: Yiu have only draft and save or you have others condition to test ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `elseif`:

```
<?php if ($model->isDraft()): ?>
    <a class="btn btn-sd btn-sd-ghost btn-sd-ghost-black full-width" href="#confirm-popup">Add More IDE <i class="icon-arr-down"></i></a>
<?php elseif ($model->save()): ?> 
    <a class="btn btn-sd btn-sd-ghost btn-sd-ghost-black full-width" href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('//idea/frontend/explore') ?>">Add More IDE <i class="icon-arr-down"></i></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 1):

May be this should help you:

```
<?php if($model->isDraft()){ ?>
      <a class="btn btn-sd btn-sd-ghost btn-sd-ghost-black full-width" href="#confirm-popup">Add More IDE <i class="icon-arr-down"></i></a>
<?php } else if($model->save()){ ?> 
      <a class="btn btn-sd btn-sd-ghost btn-sd-ghost-black full-width" href="<?php echo $this->createUrl('//idea/frontend/explore'); ?>">Add More IDE <i class="icon-arr-down"></i></a>
<?php } ?>
```